# Is there any library in C# that change human voice timbre

Tags: c#, voice

I'm searching for library that change timbre of human voice. I want to make small changes like: change deep male voice to little bit higher (something like change bass to tenor).
I think that changing voice in wider range - changing male voice to woman voice is too complicated and there is no good tool to do that, Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SoundTouch](http://code.google.com/p/soundtouchnet/) is an open-source audio processing library for changing the Tempo, Pitch and Playback Rates of audio streams or audio files.

I think that changing the Pitch is what you're looking for...

Comment: Looks interesting - it changes pitch of voice, I have to check how natural it sounds. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like this may be able to do what you're talking about: http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/